# Javascript replace regex using

Tags: javascript

I need to change @x ( x a number) to x.
How can I do that, I don't know js regex..

Comment: Answers where already posted and I can't comment on the question, but [here is a link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to regex in javascript if you want to learn more about it.

Comment: It's pretty straight forward, you can try to learn something about regex [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) give it a try if you still face any problem comment here will be happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

> `var n = Number(s.replace(/\D+/, ''))`

```
> var s = "@123";
undefined
> 
> var n = s.replace(/\D+/, '')
undefined
> 
> n
'123'
> 
> n = Number(n)
123
> 
> n + 7
130
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `replace` like so:

```js
 

const str = "@1235";
const num = str.replace("@", "");
console.log(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inbuilt `replace` function for this purpose, which can take both, literals and regex pattern as parameter.

```
var str = "@12345";
str.replace("@", "");
```

We can also use patterns in the replace parameter, if you have multiple values to be replaced.

```
var str = "@123#45";
str.replace(/[@#]/,"")     // prints "123#45" => removes firs occurrence only
str.replace(/[@#]/g,"")    // prints "12345"
str.replace(/\D/,"")       // prints "123#45"  => removes any non-digit, first occurrence
str.replace(/\D/g,"")      // prints "12345"  => removes any non-digit, all occurrence
```

- `g` stands for global search
- [@#] stands for either `@` or `#`, you can add anything here
- \D stands for anything other than digits